# Directly accessing get/post variables without explicitly accessing $_GET / $_POST

Tags: php

I am trying to refactor old PHP project, and this project does not access $_GET, $_POST variables explicitly. For example, it just uses `$ab` instead of `$_POST['ab']`. My local server does not allow that right now.

How can I change my `php.ini` setting such that I can directly access those $_POST and $_GET variables without referrencing them with $_GET and $_POST?

I need to do this through server-wise setting because there are just so many files to add 2 lines of settings on the top.

Comment: I am doing it to refactor the old project codes...

Comment: Take a look at [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In php.ini set the `register_globals` option to `'on'`

This is very **very** bad practice, however, and I suggest you make this temporary.

Comment: Yeah, I just need to temporarily enable it to refactor the old project codes, and server is in local so it should be safe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use the `$_REQUEST` superglobal array; it contains a merge of the `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` and `$_SESSION` arrays. But if you really sure that you need to use `register_globals`, you can turn it `on`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function import_request_variables.
Just add a line

```
import_request_variables("gp","");
```

to a global include file.

So you DON'T have to turn on register_global ON.

Here is more information about it http://php.net/manual/en/function.import-request-variables.php